# Checking Email notifications in Outlook using selenium Webdrivers

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate a cloud environment. The process goes like I submit a request.
On request submission, an email is sent by SharePoint to Administrator group about the request submission.
Now what I am supposed to do is to check weather an email is being sent to them or not along with email bodies and links. I tried searching a lot but could not find a way for doing it.
Please help.

Comment: The mail goes to outlook.

Comment: Is the outlook mail, a webmail or desktop application ?

Comment: Outlook is a web mail. After submitting the request, mail is being sent to Outlook web app of Admins. Its SMTP server

Comment: Where is the point that you are struck up? Have you written some code for selenium webdriver using java or any other programming language?

Comment: I am using selenium webdriver through Java. Actually am not getting how to start with even. Like I have written the code to submit my Request now. But my next step is testing weather an email is being fired at the time of submission or not

Comment: I am not getting a way of testing weather an email is being sent or not.

Comment: For checking the emails, you need to open the concerned outlook webapp link and give username and password and then perform validations using Junit or TestNG. If you want me to provide some startup code, you can send me the link if it is not confidential.

Comment: I am using Junit. Outlook webApp will be opened.. say I provide username and password and log in. How to verify and check if the concerned email is present there or not? the outlook webapp link is https://mail.microsoft.com.

Comment: You can check for link text... by comparing the subject of the mail. after clicking the link(if the link text assertion is passed), you can check for body header whether it is present in the htmlsource obtained from the webdriver's getPageSource() method.

Comment: I will try and let you know.. Thanx for the help.. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you use c# code to read the mail.

```
Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.NameSpace olNameSpace = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi");
            Outlook.MAPIFolder oInbox  = olNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
            Outlook.Items oItems  = oInbox.Items;
            Console.WriteLine("Total : " + oItems.Count);
            oItems = oItems.Restrict("[Unread] = true");
            Console.WriteLine("Total Unread : " + oItems.Count); //Unread Items
            Outlook.MailItem oMsg;

            for (int i = 0; i < oItems.Count; i++)
            {
                oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oItems.GetFirst();


                //oMsg.Display(true);

                Console.WriteLine(oMsg.Links);
                IE browser1 = new IE(oMsg.Links);
                Console.WriteLine(oMsg.SenderName);
                Console.WriteLine(oMsg.Subject);

            }
```